# How can I auto-detect the default WAN gateway on a Cisco router?

Tags: cisco-ios

I previously connected to my ISP using authenticated PPPoE and provided default routes for IPv4 and IPv6 as follows:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer0
ipv6 route ::/0 Dialer0
```

After switching to a different ISP who provides direct Ethernet, I had to change it to this:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet1 dhcp
ipv6 route ::/0 GigabitEthernet1 FE80::xx:xx:xxxx:xx
```

However the IPv4 route is mildly intermittent, and the IPv6 route is necessarily dependent on a temporary link-local address. How can I ask the router to route packets to the single router connected directly to the WAN interface?

I found [a post](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47630/stateful-dhcpv6-default-router/47653#47653) which suggested that `no ipv6 unicast-routing` might work for IPv6, which does seem to auto-detect the default route but also causes the router to stop forwarding IPv6 packets from the LAN.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this correctly installs a route to the IPv4 and IPv6 gateways without the need for additional route configuration:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1
 ip address dhcp
 ipv6 nd autoconfig default-route
```

Comment: Yes, DHCP(v4) will set your default gateway. And IPv6 RA(s) tell you where routers are for various prefixes. (you may only see one, but the protocol is designed for multiple routers.)

Answer (score 0):

An addendum to you solution Bardi.

Point-to-point Ethernet links should not have the interface as the destination because it can cause the router to generate more ARP traffic to find a packets destination.

It’s a best practice not to specify the interface as the destination when configuring a static route (unless your using a point-to-point DSL or Serial link).

Also, the `no ipv6 unicast route` command disables routing all ipv6 unicast traffic, essentially dropping ipv6 packets.